# HTML to PDF - Table empty space

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm using `wkhtmltopdf` to turn HTML into a PDF. The goal here is to generate an invoice that mostly consists of `table`

#### Problems

When being converted a table, if its content does not fit in one page, leaves a white space.

#### Questions

How can I fix that? I'm guessing it should be fixed with a CSS property

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to reduce font-size , cell padding ?

Comment: You may also reduce the page margin

Comment: Does not seem to work :/

Comment: Did you find a solution to this Leo?

Comment: From what I remember, I did not find a one fits all solution. I had to play with the style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this class to your container element

```
.no-break{
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't work either

Comment: Thankyou, this worked for me.